# Reset accumulated lag on all kafka partitions

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-python

Good afternoon. Given: a kafka topic with more than 20 partitions and a huge message traffic and one consumer group.
It is necessary each time connecting to a topic to reset all the lag available there (with data loss) on all partitions and read it from the most recent messages.
Please tell me how to implement it. I use python + confluent-kafka. I need something like this pseudocode.

But it has two problems, I don't know how to get the list of partitions correctly and this code throws an error when trying to read from a topic.

```
def reset_offset_to_latest(consumer, partitions):
    for p in partitions:
        p.offset = confluent_kafka.OFFSET_END
    print('assign', partitions)
    consumer.assign(partitions)
```

Error:

```
cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError{code=_STATE,val=-172,str="Failed to set assignment: Local: Erroneous state"}
```

Please help!

Comment: Your code has indentation problems. Code inside a function needs to be indented. Try to paste your code into the interpreter. It will raise a SyntaxError. Though most likely this isn't what caused the exception. Since SyntaxError will prevent the code from running in the first place. But your code format in the question is wrong.

Comment: when inserting the code, the indents moved out

Comment: Don't do extra indentation, just indent the code as you would normally in the console. Use three backticks before the code block and after it.

Comment: I don't understand your pseudocode. There already is a seek_to_end function... And the assign API doesn't use consumer groups, only subscribe does